# Pacote gráfico mais rápido que o ggplot2

Tags: r

vocês conhecem algum pacote no R que concatene e faça gráficos 2D e 3D de maneira mais rápida que o ggplot2?

Answer (score 5):

O próprio `base` é muito mais rápido que o `ggplot2` em termos de tempo até a renderização do gráfico.

```
> library(ggplot2)
> dados <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   base = plot(dados$x, dados$y),
+   ggplot2 = print(ggplot(dados, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()),
+   times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
    expr        min         lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
    base   6.111439   6.297696  11.23991  13.0963  13.68068  14.21597    10
 ggplot2 137.465155 139.280801 148.73481 148.4097 155.98191 161.27931    10
```

Mas se você está tendo problemas porque o ggplot está demorando deveria considerar tirar uma amostra dos seus dados para fazer o gráfico. Geralmente para a visualização não deve fazer muita diferença.

Se você tiver tentando fazer gráficos de frequência, pode tentar agrupar os dados usando algum oputro pacote e depois usando o ggplot apenas para plotar. Por exemplo, se você quisesse fazer um gráfico de barras das cores dos diamantes (banco de dados `diamonds` do R).

Poderia fazer assim:

```
diamonds %>% 
    group_by(color) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = color, y = n)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Ao invés de fazer assim:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = color)) + geom_bar()
```

A forma usando o `dplyr` será um pouco mais rápida:

```
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 ggplot + dplyr 154.2552 159.4668 165.0565 162.5604 172.0724 180.2274    10
         ggplot 205.3213 212.5129 218.5641 217.9931 223.3510 238.7627    10
```